# Does adjoining a $p$-power divisor to an elliptic curve, where $p\neq 2$ is a prime, always result in a Galois group of order greater than $2$?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

The question says it:
Suppose I have a field $K$, whose characteristic is, for simplicity, zero, and an elliptic curve $E$ over $K$, and $x\in E(K)$.

Suppose that $p$ is a prime different from $2$, and $n\in E(\overline{K})$ with $pn=x$, $n\notin E(K)$. If $L$ is the smallest algebraic extension of $K$ so that $n\in E(L)$, is $\sharp\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)>2$?

Comment: I guess you (at least!) need to rule out cases like the following. Let's view $$E:y^2=x^3-2$$ over $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt6)$. Let $P\in E(K)$ be the point at infinity. Then the points $N_k:=(2\omega^k,\sqrt6)$, $\omega=(-1+\sqrt{-3})/2$, $k=0,1,2$ are all 3-torsion points of $E$, because $\psi_3(x)=3x^4-24x$. So $3N_1=P$, but $N_1\in E(L)$ with $L=K(\omega)$ quadratic over $K$. If we insist that $K$ is the minimal field that 1) contains the field of definition of $E$ and 2) meets the requirement $P\in E(K)$, then that would ruin this "counterexample". I don't know if there are more serious examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can’t think of negative answers to your question except when $p^r=3$. Look at the following case:

Fortunately you allowed *any* field of characteristic zero for your $K$, and I’m going to take $K=\Bbb Q_3$, and $E$ the curve $Y^2=X^3+X^2+1$ defined over $\Bbb Z_3$, with good ordinary reduction modulo $3$. The $3$-torsion points are the inflection points when the point $\Bbb O$ at infinity is taken to be the identity. I make the formula for the second derivative to be
$$
\frac{d^2Y}{dX^2}=\frac{15X^4 + 20X^3+4X^2+24X+8}{8Y^3}\,,
$$
which is zero exactly when the numerator is zero, so giving four values of $X$, each with two $Y$-values. Look at the Newton polygon of the numerator: vertices at $(0,0)$, $(3,0)$, and $(4,1)$, so that there is a $\Bbb Q_3$-rational root of the form $u/3$, where $u$ is a $3$-adic unit. This allows your point “$n$” to be $(u/3,\sqrt{u/3}\,)$, necessitating precisely a quadratic extension.

Nor is this phenomenon peculiar to $3$-torsion points. If you take your point “$x$” to be suitably close to $\Bbb O$ in the $3$-adic topology, you’ll have the same behavior, but the formulas will be a lot messier. It’s actually much easier to do this in the language of formal groups, but that’s another story.

Comment: As an addendum, maybe I should say that this worked only because the curve is *ordinary*. Most elliptic curves that you’d want to write down over $\Bbb Z_3$ would be likely to have form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, and these all have supersingular reduction if it’s good. Also, I think the right question would have been to ask whether dividing a point by $p$ necessarily gives a wildly ramified extension, and the answer is No if the curve is ordinary, and complicated in the supersingular case.